# get all recursive terms from termstore powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, powershell, term-store, term-set

I have a requirement where I need to `match a string value with all the terms` in a given `termset ID`. My termset contains terms inside terms(`recursively`) until `5 levels`.

My Current Code :

```
$TermsetData = $TermStore.GetTermSet($TermSetId);
    $ctx.Load($TermsetData);
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    $level1TermsData = $TermsetData.Terms;
    $ctx.Load($level1TermsData);
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    #match the source value with the destination terms and prepare the value string
    $termValuesStringDest = $null;  
    foreach ($objLevel1Term in $level1TermsData) {
        Write-Host $objLevel1Term.Name -ForegroundColor Red;
        if ($sourceProp -match $objLevel1Term.Name) {                                   
            $termValuesStringDest = "-1;#" + $objLevel1Term.Name + "|" + $objLevel1Term.Id;
            return $termValuesStringDest;
        }
    }
```

is there any way I can make it recursive?

I have tried recursive this way, but it is not exiting the loop.  Can anyone let me know how to break this loop and return a value?

```
function GetTermStoreRecursive() {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TermCollection]$TermsCollection,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$ctx,        
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$sourceProp
    )

    $level1TermsData = $TermsCollection;

    #match the source value with the destination terms and prepare the value string
    $termValuesStringDest = $null;  

    foreach ($objLevel1Term in $level1TermsData) {
        Write-Host $objLevel1Term.Name -ForegroundColor Red;
        if ($sourceProp -eq $objLevel1Term.Name) {
            $termValuesStringDest = "-1;#" + $objLevel1Term.Name + "|" + $objLevel1Term.Id;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $subTerms = $objLevel1Term.Terms;
            $ctx.Load($subTerms);
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            GetTermStoreRecursive $subTerms $ctx $sourceProp
        }
    }

    return $termValuesStringDest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no need for doing that recursively.

I have found out a method which gets all terms in that termstore from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/76031/20300).

```
$allTermsData = $TermsetData.GetAllTerms();
$ctx.Load($allTermsData);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```